# How to do a month search by sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 1 table in MS Access which is like:

```
id   date
1    1/01/2016
2    1/01/2016
3    1/01/2016
```

How do I perform a search operation on it by month - meaning a search where the month is January/February?

Comment: `where Month([date]) in (1,2)`

Comment: i have tried like '%/2/16' but it des not work when i take my project to aother pc becoz of change in date formate so i need a best way

Comment: Always handle date as dates not strings, no exceptions. @JimHewitt gave you the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dates as criteria in Access queries:
Contain a date within a specific month (regardless of year), such as December

```
DatePart("m", [SalesDate]) = 12
```

Returns items with a date in December of any year.
Where of course you replace [SalesDate] with your column...